# Rails: how to reload everything in developement mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, reload

I'm finding conflicting advise on how to ensure that all my code is reloaded on each request in Rails development mode. In particular, I want to make sure lib/ and app/mailers/ are reloaded.

Edit: I use WEBrick in development.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pow](http://pow.cx/). Add a file called `always_restart.txt` in the tmp directory.

Answer (score -1):

if using Passenger, just create a file called "restart.txt" inside "yourapp/tmp".

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Passenger checks if that file exists and it's creation date on every call.

If it finds it, it deletes it and restarts all the framework.

Comment: This does not help ensure "code is reloaded on each request."